# include layout is not working another layout

Tags: android, android-layout, layout, include

I created a general *layout* and included  it in to tow layouts. It's working fine my first layout but its not working in another layout.

The first layout where general layout is working:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<!--
here i am included general layout .here its working fine
-->
            <include
                layout="@layout/generalwaistlayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/wais_to_heightbtn"
                android:layout_width="21mm"
                android:layout_height="7.2mm"
                android:layout_marginTop="4mm"
                android:background="@drawable/cm"
                android:text="Calculate"
                android:textSize="2.8mm"
                android:textColor="#ffffff"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5mm"
                    android:layout_marginRight="5mm"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="14mm"
                    android:background="@drawable/mass">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="Result"
                            android:textSize="4mm"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4mm"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="8mm"

                            />
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/waisttoheightresulttext"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0.0%"
                            android:textSize="5mm"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4mm"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="15mm"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>
                  <!--  <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/bmiTextbodymasssresult"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="0.0%"
                            android:textSize="5mm"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3mm"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6mm"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>-->
                 <!--   <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="vertical"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="right"
                            android:text="N/A"
                            android:textSize="5mm"
                            android:layout_marginTop="3mm"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6mm"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>-->

                </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/extremelyslimlayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="1mm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="3mm"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="4mm"
                    android:layout_height="4mm"
                    android:src="@drawable/weight"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="37mm"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Extremely Slim"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1mm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0mm"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Less than 0.34"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/healthylayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="4mm"
                    android:layout_height="4mm"
                    android:src="@drawable/health"
                    />
<!--
                android:id="@+id/waistToHeighthealthy_name"
-->

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="37mm"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Healthy "
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0mm"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/waistToHeighthealthy"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1mm"
                    android:text="0.43 to 0.52"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/overweightlayouts"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="4mm"
                    android:layout_height="4mm"
                    android:src="@drawable/slim"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="37mm"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Overweight"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0mm"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/waistToHeightoverweight"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1mm"
                    android:text="0.53 to 0.57"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/veryoverweightlayouts"

                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="4mm"
                    android:layout_height="4mm"
                    android:src="@drawable/over"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="37mm"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Very Overweight"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0mm"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/waistToHeightveryoverweight"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1mm"
                    android:text="0.58 to 0.62"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/morbidlyobeselayout"
                android:layout_marginLeft="0.5mm"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="4mm"
                    android:layout_height="4mm"
                    android:src="@drawable/very"
                    />
                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="37mm"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Morbidly Obese"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0mm"/>

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/waistToHeightobese"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1mm"
                    android:text="Greater than 0.63"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
<!--
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="1mm"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:layout_width="4mm"
                    android:layout_height="4mm"
                    android:src="@drawable/obese"
                    />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="37mm"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Morbidly Obese"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0mm"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1mm"
                    android:text="18.5 - 24.9"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    />

            </LinearLayout>
-->
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3mm"
                android:background="#a1a1a1"/>
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

The second layout where *general layouts* is not working:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <!--
        here i am include general layout here is not working
        -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/generalwaistlayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
    <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="2.5mm"
            android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Neck"
                android:textColor="#009788"
                android:textSize="3.5mm"
                android:layout_marginTop="1mm"
                />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/body_fat_per_neck_edittext"
                android:layout_width="18mm"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                />
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/necktogglelayout"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="4mm"
                >
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/neck_toggle_textview"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="4mm"
                    android:textSize="3mm"
                    android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                    android:text="cm"
                    android:textColor="#009788"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="3mm"

                    />
                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:background="@drawable/arrowdropdowngrey27x27"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/calculate_body_fat_percentage"
            android:layout_width="21mm"
            android:layout_height="7.2mm"
            android:layout_marginTop="4mm"
            android:background="@drawable/cm"
            android:text="Calculate"
            android:textSize="2.8mm"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5mm"
            android:layout_marginRight="5mm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="14mm"
            android:background="@drawable/mass">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"

                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Result"
                    android:textSize="4mm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8mm"

                    />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/body_fat_per_result"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="0.0%"
                    android:textSize="5mm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="4mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="15mm"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!--  <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                  <TextView
                      android:id="@+id/bmiTextbodymasssresult"
                      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:text="0.0%"
                      android:textSize="5mm"
                      android:layout_marginTop="3mm"
                      android:layout_marginLeft="6mm"
                      />
              </LinearLayout>-->
            <!--   <LinearLayout
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:orientation="vertical"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                   <TextView
                       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                       android:layout_gravity="right"
                       android:text="N/A"
                       android:textSize="5mm"
                       android:layout_marginTop="3mm"
                       android:layout_marginLeft="6mm"
                       />
               </LinearLayout>-->

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1mm"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="4mm"
                android:layout_height="4mm"
                android:src="@drawable/slim"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="41mm"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Healthy Slim"
                android:textSize="3mm"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                android:layout_marginTop="0mm"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8%"
                android:textSize="3mm"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1mm"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="4mm"
                android:layout_height="4mm"
                android:src="@drawable/health"
                />
            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="36mm"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Healthy"
                android:textSize="3mm"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                android:layout_marginTop="0mm"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="8 - 20%"
                android:textSize="3mm"
                />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="1mm"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal">
            <ImageView
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_width="4mm"
                android:layout_height="4mm"
                android:src="@drawable/over"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_width="34.5mm"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Overwieght"
                android:textSize="3mm"
                android:layout_marginLeft="2mm"
                android:layout_marginTop="0mm"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="20 - 25%"
                android:textSize="3mm" />

        </LinearLayout>


        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1.5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="2mm"
            android:background="#a1a1a1"/>


        <LinearLayout

            android:layout_marginTop="0mm"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5mm"
            android:layout_marginRight="5mm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="14mm">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left"
                    android:text="Result"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:textSize="4mm"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="4mm"
                    />


            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="28.4 - 34.3"
                    android:textSize="4mm"
                    android:textColor="#000000"
                    android:layout_marginTop="1mm"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="18mm"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

Ok, now its my general layout which i am including in tow different layouts The name of this layout is `gernalwaistlayout`:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="2.5mm"
        android:layout_marginLeft="45dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Waist"
            android:id="@+id/heightTextView"
            android:textColor="#009788"
            android:textSize="3.5mm"
            android:layout_marginTop="1mm"
            />
        <EditText
            android:inputType="number"
            android:id="@+id/gernal_waist_edit"
            android:layout_width="18mm"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="1mm"
            />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/waisttogglelayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="4mm"
            >
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/waist_toggle_textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="4mm"
                android:textSize="3mm"
                android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
                android:text="cm"
                android:textColor="#009788"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3mm"
                />
            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/arrowdropdowngrey27x27"
                />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

**this is my curent output and waist is not working **
[image]

[image]

Comment: May be your activity crosses the screen height

Comment: Make a ScrollView as your main parent and move the current parent LinearLayout as child

Answer (score 1):

May be your activity crosses the screen height. To solve this, create a `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView` as your parent layout and move the `current parent LinearLayout` as child of `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

Comment: @Rehankhan paste your screenshort here. What is your current output

Comment: @Rehankhan try with `android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView`

Comment: please check my current output

Comment: sir i am including my garnalwaitlayout in tow layout .its works fine in one ,layout and in other  not working

Comment: @Rehankhan Ok you are including the same layout in two different layouts. and in one its working and in another its not. Is this is your problem right ? Ok I'll check the codes and update my answer

Comment: yes exactly .you got it.  i am waiting of your response

Comment: Make the first two `LinearLayout` and the include statement width as match_parent and try - Remove the height and width attribute of include its not necessarily needed @Rehankhan